# Rational function interpolation?

Tags: interpolation, rational-functions

We know that $n+1$ points is enough to completely determine a polynomial of degree $n$. Are there any techniques which says that a certain number of points is enough to completely determine a rational function $r(x)=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q\in\mathbb{R}[x]$? What if we know a bound on the degree of the numerator or denominator?

Comment: It should be clear that you at least need bounds on the degrees.  Every polynomial is a rational function.

Comment: If you know bounds $\deg p, \deg q$ on the degrees of the numerator and denominator then it takes $\deg p + \deg q + 1$ points.